Is a Lorentz transformation allowing an infinite value $c$ still a proper Lorentz transformation?
Is it correct to say that inertial systems are related by Lorentz transformations even if we do not know if the "invariant speed" is finite or infinite? To me, this is incorrect because $c$ being finite or infinite makes the critical distinction between the Lorentz and Galilean transformations.
But I see mixed accounts on this. For instance, Essential Radio Astronomy mentions Lorentz transformations while assuming $c$ could be finite or infinite:

The Lorentz transform is the only coordinate transform consistent with both relativity and the existence of some still-unspecified invariant speed $c$  (for example, the vacuum speed of light, or even $\infty$). The assumption that there exists some invariant speed is actually weaker than assuming $t=t′$  because it turns out that $c=\infty$ reduces the Lorentz transform to the Galilean transform.

To me this is not entirely correct, because a "Lorentz transformation" with a "still-unspecified" invariant speed that can be $\infty$ is not a true Lorentz transformation. We are still undecided on whether the transformation is Lorentzian or Galilean.
Am I wrong?

Well, if $c$ were infinite then as noted the Lorentz reduces to the Galilean transformation. Consider the Galilean transformation as a special case of the Lorentz transformation. That’s all.

@jon, so the Galilean transformation is a special case of the Euclidean transformation as well? And is Newtonian mechanics Lorentz invariant? The whole point of "reduces to" suggests a limiting case, rather than a special case. For instance, let $n$ be a natural number, however $\lim_{n \to \infty}$ is not.

From a strict mathematical perspective, it's nonsense to say that $c=\infty$ is a valid "value" for $c$. I think a more careful statement is that the Lorentz transformations have a parameter $c$. You can take a limit in which this parameter goes to infinity, and in that limit the Lorentz transformations reduce to the Galilean transformations. The fancy name for this is group contraction.

Newtonian mechanics is non-relativistic, so is Lorentz invariant for an infinite $c$. We now know $c$ is finite, and can do relativistic mechanics just fine.

@Andrew - many mathematical entities can be infinite. It is easy to imagine a universe where $c$ is infinite - we did that already with Newtonian mechanics. But the universe does not work that way. However, for human-scale velocities classical mechanics works just fine.

@JonCuster, I'm trrying to understand how this lack of rigorous terminology doesn't get one into trouble. You seem to suggest that it's fine to say that NM is Lorentz invariant.

Well it is, in the limit of $c$ being infinite. Why does anything get into trouble here?

Let $n$ be a natural number and $\lim_{n \to \infty} = \infty$. Doesn't your reasoning suggest $\infty$ is a special case of the natural numbers, in the same way the Galilean transformation is a special case of the Lorentz transformation?

The Galilean group (which is the symmetry group of non-relativistic mechanics) is a different group from the Lorentz group, although it can be obtained from a limit of the Lorentz group when $c\rightarrow \infty$ as a group contraction. Saying that "the Galilean group is a special case of the Lorentz group when $c=\infty$" is confusing and mathematically sloppy, but it can be unpacked into the more precise statement about limits I gave previously. Also technically we should say "Poincaire group" instead of "Lorentz group."

@andrew, don't you want to formulate your comments as an answer?

Sure, I guess it turned into an answer anyway :)

From a mathematical perspective, it doesn't make sense to say $c=\infty$. Rather, one should talk about a limit where $c\rightarrow \infty$.
The Lorentz transformations (rotations and boosts, and combinations of those), plus translations, form the Poincaire group, which is the symmetry group of special relativity. In physics, we typically define the members of the Poincaire group to include a parameter $c$.
There is another group, called the Galilean group, which is the symmetry group of non-relativistic Newtonian mechanics. It also corresponds to boosts, rotations, and translations, although the transformation rules are different. The Galilean group is a different group from the Poincaire group.
However, through the process of group contraction, it is possible to obtain the Galilean group as a limit of the Poincaire group, when we take the limit $c\rightarrow \infty$. This is a precise sense in which non-relativistic physics "lives inside" of special relativity.

Thanks @andrew. The answer rather suggests non-relativistic physics is strictly speaking not "living inside" special relativity. $1$ is not living inside $(0,1)$, while lim 0.99999.... = 1.

This seems to be a problem with nomenclature, not really physics. You can give the name "Lorentz transformation" to whichever case you see fit, and the matter ends up being whether this definition is in agreement with most of the scientific community. In other words, there is nothing that forbids you from calling the Galilean transformations a particular case of the Lorentz transformations, apart from whether other people will also like your definition.
Once it is clear that this is just a matter of convention, I will complete this answer with a personal opinion that reflects how I see this nomenclature. Usually, the Lorentz transformations are presented with the goal of opposing the Galilean transformations: the important point tends to be not whether they are similar, but rather that they are different. Hence, I think it might be misleading (for young students at least) to present the Lorentz transformations as a generalization of the Galilean transformations.
The argument given in the paragraph you quoted is correct, in the sense that the Galilean transformations are a limiting case of the Lorentz transformations. In a more group-theoretic parlance, the Galilean group is a İnönü–Wigner contraction of the Lorentz group, which is just the technical way of saying "it is the $c \to \infty$ limit of the Lorentz group". For completeness, I'd like to mention that sometimes one often discusses the $c \to 0$ limit of the Lorentz group, which leads to the so-called Carroll group, originally discussed by Lévy-Leblond in the 1960s in a paper in French.
A possible argument against calling the Galilean transformations Lorentz transformations can be made in the context of General Relativity. Newtonian gravity is a limit of General Relativity in the sense that taking $c \to \infty$ in GR leads to Newton–Cartan. Since Newton–Cartan clearly does not present the structure of GR (for example, it does not have a Lorentzian metric), maybe it is a bad idea to call Galilean transformations a particular case of Lorentz transformations.
Something, however, should be crystal clear: to my knowledge, there is no consensus on whether a Galilean transformation is a Lorentz transformation. Different authors may use different conventions, and there is no a priori physical reason to prefer one over the other. The best we can do is give reasons for it and reasons against it. Asking which one is right is similar to ask whether a Lorentzian metric should have signature $-+++$ or $+---$: the physics doesn't depend on it, as long as you are clear and consistent.

Thanks for clarifying in an articulate way. That the lorentz transformation reduces to the galilean transformation is a well known fact, not questioned here. My point is that many people seem to assume that because the galilean transformation is a limiting case of the lorentz transformation, then it follows that the galilean transformation is a lorentz transformation with a specific value of $c$. I'm questioning that. The limit of $0.9999999..... = 1$ but $1$ is not a special case of the open segment $(0,1)$.

Actually, @andrew addresses this point directly: "From a strict mathematical perspective, it's nonsense to say that $c=\infty$
is a valid "value" for $c$. I think a more careful statement is that the Lorentz transformations have a parameter c. You can take a limit in which this parameter goes to infinity, and in that limit the Lorentz transformations reduce to the Galilean transformations."

I suspect there is a mixture of terminology when saying the $c=\infty$ the lorentz transformation reduces to the galilean transformation: setting $c$ to a specific value while "reduces" suggest a limit.

@RealPattern Whether a Galilean transformation is a Lorentz transformatiom is just a matter of nomenclature, as I said in the first paragraph. You can choose whichever option you prefer, and other people will choose whichever option they prefer. However, I agree with Andrew that it seems strange to consider $c = \infty$ rather than $c \to \infty$

Well, isn't the use of any word a matter of nomenclature? Doesn't the scientific and mathematical community share @andrew's concern?

@RealPattern The traditional definition of the Lorentz transformation is actually given for $c = 299792458 \mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}$. It makes sense to extend the definition for arbitrary $c$. It is a matter of choice whether you also want to extend it to $c = \infty$ or even $c=0$. I know of no consensus on this topic, so it ends up being up to you

After revising the galilean transform it appears to be non-relativistic.
So the answer for "whether we can call, in a rigorous sense, the galilean transformation a special case of the lorentz transformation or not" is NO.
the concept c (speed of light) =oo is pure theoretic, or better said "erratic" and not based on physical evidence
kins regards,

@Real pattern: the best way to pursue the infiniteness of the speed of light c is in or through unknown matter, exotic matter, dark matter etc. It depends on the relative permittivity of the medium.The formula for the speed of light that can be used as a thumb rule is (as a consequence of the linear propagation model determined by D’Lambert wave-equation and the electro-magnetic Field equations by Maxwell)
c := 1/sqrt( mu_0mu_repsilon_0*epsilon_r),mu_0= magnetic permittivity medium, r = relative ,epsilon_0= electric permittivity medium

Nothing to do with the question.
